# Difference between single layer and multilayer PCB?

Tags: pcb, pcb-fabrication

Please answer my question
Difference between single layer and multi layer PCB ?

Comment: Yes, there is a difference

Comment: Question ahould be closed - insuffucient research.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please quickly realise that this is not a free design house, homework-answering service or an on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your questions shows that you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which your post doesn't, I'm afraid. Please revise your question showing your work and findings so far in detail. Or delete the question if Internet searches give you your answer anyway. Again, a warm welcome to the site.

Answer (score 3):

In PCB terminology, the amount of "layers" refers to the amount of conductor layers.

A single layer (usually called "single side") board has only one layer of conductor. However, this is often not enought: you cannot have lines cross without using a cable, and you might not have enough space if you need large amounts of power distribution. For this reason, we add more layers.
A two-layer has conductors on both sides. The sides can usually be connected with what we call a "via" (pronounced veeeh-ja or vaj-a, depending on who you ask).

However, we often want (or need) even more layers. These are what people often call "multi layer" boards. This image is an example of a 10 layer board:

[image: 10 layer pcb crossection]

The horizontal lines are the layers. The lines going between them are vias.

Often, there is a certain structure in these layers.
One common structure is using a 4 layer board. The top and bottom are used for signal. One of the two internal layers is used for ground, the second for powerdistribution. 
Another common structure used in RF design is to use the top layer as a RF layer and the second layer as a ground. This is usually accompanied with the use of a special substrate layer between them. The bottom is then used for low-speed signals and the third is again power.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is simply how many layers of copper there are. A single-layer PCB has copper traces on only one side of the board, a two-layer PCB has traces on both sides, and a multi-layer PCB has some traces in the middle as well.

Comment: A multilayer pcb has has thinner dialectic between the copper layers in comparison to a two layer board of the same final thickness.